# Wordpress how to add a custom class to Author name for styling purposes

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, styles

I have this code below to display author name under post titles, but how would I assign a class to it so I can change its style using css, like its color and font size etc?

`<?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>`

Comment: Hi, I have put up an answer, but in general it can be useful to use your browser's dev tools inspect facility to look at the element. That way you can see exactly what code the Wordpress function is putting onto your page (I found the Wordpress Codex not very clear as to whether it was outputting just the URL or a complete anchor element, turns out it was the latter).

Answer (score 1):

the_author_posts_link actually echoes an anchor tag of this form

```
<a href="https://somewebsite.com/author/john-smith/" title="Posts by john.smith" rel="author">John.Smith</a>
```

The simplest way of formatting it is probably to wrap it in a div say which has a unique class which you can style in the Wordpress backend at Appearance>Cusomize

```
<div class="myAuthorStyle"><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></div>
```

A simple example of styling:

```css
.myAuthorStyle a {
  color: magenta;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="myAuthorStyle"><a href="https://somewebsite.com/author/john-smith/" title="Posts by john.smith" rel="author">John.Smith</a></div>
```